# Change console logging name of object extended from built-in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, console.log, es6-class

I have a basic class extending Array like the following:

```
class Vector extends Array {
  constructor(array) {
    // doesn't handle special case of length 1 array
    super(...array);
  }
  // more code
}
```

Even if I try to change the `name` and `toString` prototypes, I still get it printed as `Array`:

```
Vector.constructor.prototype.toString = () => "Vector";
new Vector([1,2,3]) // shows Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ] in Firefox console
```

How can I get the class to show up as `Vector(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]` in console?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're right, I just tested Chromium and node. Maybe it is a Firefox specific feature

Comment: Even I tried in Edge it works properly. Seems to be a firefox issue.

Comment: @DevAnanth Edge *is* Chrome...

Comment: The javascript spec allows for a given browser to log an object more or less however it wants
`"How the implementation prints args is up to the implementation, but implementations should separate the objects by a space or something similar, as that has become a developer expectation."`


https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Edge/Chrome/node who use V8 engine try to be smart and show object as `Vector` in console. You don't need the line `Vector.constructor.prototype.toString = () => "Vector";` for that to happen, they will show it anyway as `Vector`

Firefox on the other hand seems to show only JS built-in types in the console output. For simple class it will show `Object`. But chrome will show class name.

Secondly, your understanding on JS Object model is incorrect. `Vector.constructor` is not your constructor function on your line 2. But it is a constructor from which Vector class is made. Remember ultimately, `class` is a `function` and `function` in JS is first class objects.

Since Vector is a `function` it is created from `Function` object. Hence:

```
Vector.constructor === Function
// true
```

`Function` is constructor for all functions in JS. So what you are effectively doing is changing all functions:

```
Vector.constructor.prototype.toString = () => "Vector";
// effectively means
// Function.prototype.toString = () => "Vector";

// we can test it
function anyFunction() {}
anyFunction.toString()
// "Vector"
```

Your `constructor` on your line 2 is really represented by `Vector` itself.

```
Vector.prototype.toString = () => "Vector";
(new Vector([1,2])).toString();
// "Vector"
```

Same thing can be represented by overriding in class syntax:

```
class Vector extends Array {
  // .. your code...
  toString() {
        return "Vector [" + super.toString() + "]";
  }
}

(new Vector([1,2])).toString()
// "Vector [1,2]"
```

Unfortunately, though it will not meet your original expectations.

To invoke `toString` from `console.log` you can have some concatenation:

```
let v = new Vector([1,2])
console.log("Variable is " + v)
// "Variable is Vector [1,2]"
```

Comment: @qwr - no worries, see my updates for better explanation.